# How do I edit files in network locations in Windows 10?

Tags: ftp, windows-networking

I added a network location in Windows 10 as FTP (something like this tutorial: [Setup an FTP disk in Windows Vista and 7](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/ftp-windows-7). I can access all the files, but I can't edit them like other files in other hard drives. How can I edit files in this network location?

Comment: Please don't post in all-caps, that's considered shouting. It's been edited for you, but please keep this in mind the next time you post.

Answer (score 2):

FTP protocol does not support editing files. The files will have to be transfered, edited and transfered back when done.